# Problem updating Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, lost Internet connection while installing flash plugin

Tags: 12.04, updates

I have a problem updating Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I have lost Internet connection while installing flash plugin, but I have recovered the Internet connection but it has not continue the installation with 20 minutes left.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will remove any unnecessary and partially downloaded files and upgrade all the files.